# Jquery multi Json to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, list, arraylist

I'm trying to get all JSON generate a HTML with the `<li></ li>` but did not generate he does not keep data on "HTML_all".

JSON are the same in both folders, just different data (name, icon, module, etc) I want is to gather all JSON (of those 2 module or many more) and generate a HTML with all those data together (in list / notifications). What could the error be? Thanks!

demo2 JSON:

```
[{
    "module": "demo2",
    "id": 1,
    "icon": "fa fa-hdd",
    "text": "probando noti",
    "link": "www.google.es",
    "datum": "2016-04-04"
}, {
    "module": "demo2",
    "id": 2,
    "icon": "fa fa-happpy",
    "text": "holaa",
    "link": "www.bing.es",
    "datum": "2016-06-12"
}]
```

HDD JSON:

```
[{
    "module": "hdd",
    "id": 1,
    "icon": "xxxxxx",
    "text": "hdd nicht da",
    "link": "www.google.es",
    "datum": "2016-05-31"
}, {
    "module": "hdd",
    "id": 2,
    "icon": "xxxxx",
    "text": "holaa",
    "link": "www.bing.es",
    "datum": "2016-05-31"
}]
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var html = "";
    var html_all = "";
    var json_urls = ['./modules/demo2/_notifications.php', './modules/hdd/_notifications.php'];
    for (var i = 0; i < json_urls.length; i++) {
        GetJSONArray(json_urls[i]);
    }

    //var items = [];
    function GetJSONArray(url) {
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            //console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                //items.push('<ul class="menu"> <li> <a href="'+ val.link +'"> <i class="'+ val.icon +' text-aqua"></i>'+ val.text +' '+key+' </a> </li></ul>' );
                html += '<ul class="menu"> <li> <a href="' + val.link + '"> <i class="' + val.icon + ' text-aqua"></i>' + val.text + ' </a> </li></ul>-------';
            });
            console.log("HTML OK :    " + html);
            html_all += html;
        });
    }
    console.log("HTML ?? :     " + html);
    console.log("HTML ALL :    " + html_all);
    //console.log("Items: " + items);
});
```

Console Log:

```
HTML ?? :     
_demo_notifications.html:45 HTML ALL :    
_demo_notifications.html:36 HTML OK :    <ul class="menu"> <li> <a href="www.google.es"> <i class="xxxxxx text-aqua"></i>hdd nicht da </a> </li></ul>-------<ul class="menu"> <li> <a href="www.bing.es"> <i class="xxxxx text-aqua"></i>holaa </a> </li></ul>-------
_demo_notifications.html:36 HTML OK :    <ul class="menu"> <li> <a href="www.google.es"> <i class="xxxxxx text-aqua"></i>hdd nicht da </a> </li></ul>-------<ul class="menu"> <li> <a href="www.bing.es"> <i class="xxxxx text-aqua"></i>holaa </a> </li></ul>-------<ul class="menu"> <li> <a href="www.google.es"> <i class="fa fa-hdd text-aqua"></i>probando noti </a> </li></ul>-------<ul class="menu"> <li> <a href="www.bing.es"> <i class="fa fa-happpy text-aqua"></i>holaa </a> </li></ul>-------
```

Comment: Could you maybe edit and clarify your question? Re-write it or something, I really can't understand what you're asking or even what you're saying.

Comment: Post the error maybe, how are we supposed to know what your error is?

Comment: html_all is empty .... I want for every JSON create the html with LI tags and then eventually catch all the LI and merge them into HTML only then will write in a DIV

Comment: can you show the console.log results?

Comment: @jelleB i edit the post :)

Comment: Could you please post the console logs in the right order... You have 4 log results while you call the console log only 3 times in code. It's very hard to put any effort in this post